# How to make inverted mask and allow clicks to work on masked area and not work on the remainiing Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mask, raycasting

I'm working on making interactive tutorials for my game, where for example a hand image will guide the user where to click next and at the same time will also show some info about the game rules.

[image]

For example, in the attached image I created an inverted mask following this tutorial by code monkey https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJJl19N2KFM&t=80s

over button 1, I want the clicks to work on the circled area only. How can I achieve this?

Buttons are on a different canvas and all masking stuff are on another canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [UnmaskForUGUI](https://github.com/mob-sakai/UnmaskForUGUI). It is a free plugin and can be achieved by using `UnmaskRaycastFilter`. I actually use it in my projects for the same purpose as yours.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who might wonder why suggestions from the Code Monkey video do not work in Unity 2021.3 - the code requires a few minor tweaks:

1. SetInt has since been deprecated
2. _StencilComp property - made into a float.
3. Use SetFloat and cast as float instead

Final result:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

public class UIMaskFilter : Image {
    public override Material materialForRendering {
        get {
            Material material = new Material(base.materialForRendering);
            material.SetFloat("_StencilComp", (float)CompareFunction.NotEqual);
            return material;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesnt work in Unity 2022.3.5f1 :(